# Database not showing in Schema section of MySQL Workbench for non-global access user

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a user who has been given various GRANTs on specific tables in a database, and, when connecting to the database server in MySQL Workbench (Mac and Windows), can only see the schemas to which he has been granted global privileges (e.g. SELECT on other_db.*) and not the schema for which he has been given specific, non-global GRANTs.

This is specific to MySQL Workbench, and in particular, to the Schema “browser” section in the side-bar, as there is no problem with him seeing the objects when connecting via the command-line client (or rather myself doing so with his credentials) and he can even issue queries against the database tables in the query window, once a “use database” statement has been issued (again, in both the Mac and Windows versions).

Does anyone have an idea of what may be going on here?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: I think this has been resolved by updating MySQL Workbench. It seems to no longer be an issue in 6.3.10 (for Mac, anyway).